# How to use http instead of https in url in NopCommerce

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, nopcommerce

I am working in Nop Commerce 3.0 ( using visual studio 2012 web Express edition). We already done a projects in Nop Commerce 3.0. and now the website is available in the internet. Last week we found a popup in firefox and IE browsers because our webpage contains mixed contents.

I mean some image refer from the http://ourwebsite.com/image/a1.jpg and another image refer from https://ourwebsite.com/image/a2.jpg. After see this problem we replace all the **http** string to **https** in entire soultion. But now we are facing a clueless issue.
all the a tag hrefs are "https://". Every links are goes to "https". Our home page comes in http but every inner page links contains "https". This is not valid path.

How can we solve this issue?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is arise from the database. I get this information from the nopCommerce

Help Center website.I follow the below answer.

**In order to disable SSL connect to your database, open [Store] table and set [SslEnabled] column to 0 for your store record (for nopCommerce 3.00)**

Question link : http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/23973/help-site-broken-after-setting-ssl-cant-login.aspx

Thank you very much NopCommerce